# Granular permissions for document types instead of nodes Umbraco

Tags: permissions, umbraco, umbraco7

At the user permission section of a group you can select for each node what the group can do. But is it also possible for each document type.

### Example

The group `editors` can for the document type `sitemap` can only browse node, document type `language` only publish, create, browse node and update.

### Current situation

Now I must create a node inside the three type of `language` with name `ru` and in the granular permissions section of the editors group I must select `ru` again and allow only publish, create, browse node and update.

### Question

Isn't it simpler to select document types instead of the nodes individual? I got 6 document types where the editors has less permissions in 4 different languages = 24 different nodes.